# How to assing the return of command Disconnect-AzWvdUserSession to a variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am doing a maintenance in one POwershell script and I believe that there are a conceptual issue on it.

In the script below it is supposed that the variable $ok will have a boolean on it after the execution of the command "Disconnect-AzWvdUserSession".

My Doubt is : Will the variable $ok really have a boolean on it..?
This is the correct way to check the result of command execution ?

Thanks in advance.

```
$ok = Disconnect-AzWvdUserSession -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -HostPoolName $vdiPool -SessionHostName "$hn.petrobras.biz" -Id $sid
    if ($ok) {
        Write-Host "Logoff de sess&atilde;o em $hn foi realizado!"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Problemas para realizar logoff de sess&atilde;o em $hn!"
    }
```

Comment: According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.desktopvirtualization/disconnect-azwvdusersession?view=azps-7.2.0#outputs) it _should_ be a boolean, but you can check with `$ok.GetType().FullName`

Comment: This is stranger because I did a test and the return of $ok is empty, it do not contain TRUE or FALSE. But the UserSession was disconnected.

Comment: I guess the documentation doesn't mention that the only way to have a boolean returned is by adding the `-PassThru` switch...

Comment: You got it right Theo ... I added -PassThru to the command and the value of variable $ok return TRUE.   Thank you.